# Why isn't my custom tool bar appearing on my CKEditor

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

I have followed through a tutorial on the CKEditor website but I can't figure out why my custom tool bar is not appearing on the CKEditor. Originally I had all of the default toolbar on, but now it has reverted to just being a text area. Can someone help please? The code is as follows:

```
$(function () {

    CKEDITOR.replace('txtBodyText', 
        config.toolbar=[
             { name: 'basicstyles', items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline'] },
             { name: 'list', items: ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList'] },
             { name: 'Indent', items: ['Outdent', 'Indent'] },
             { name: 'align', items: ['JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock'] },
             { name: 'links', items: ['link', 'unlink;'] },
             { name: 'insert', items: [ 'Image', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule'] },
             { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Font', 'FontSize'] },
             { name: 'Clipboard', items: ['Cut', 'Copy', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord'},
             { name: 'undo', items: [ 'Undo', 'Redo'] },
             { name: 'tools', items: [ 'Maximise'] },
             { name: 'mode', items: [ 'Source'] }

        ]);
})


 <td class="prompt">Body</td>
            <td>
                <%: Html.TextArea("txtBodyText", Model.EmailTemplate.BodyText)%>
            </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an extra pair of brackets at the bottom. If there is a problem in the Javascript it will not run the whole segment of code. So it's best to check!

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look like a valid second argument to the replace function. This might be of assistance:

```
var configObject = {};
configObject.toolbar = [
    [ 'Source', '-', 'NewPage', 'Preview', '-', 'Templates' ],
    [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo' ],
    '/',
    [ 'Bold', 'Italic' ]
];
CKEDITOR.replace('txtBodyText', configObject);
```

See the difference between the two? The 2nd argument to replace needs to be a valid JavaScript object. There was a typo in your example: see `unlink;`? That's not really correct :).

Comment: I see. I took your advice and implemented it. It still did not work, although I see your logic. I'm not quite sure why it didn't work.

Comment: @AndrewKilburn Do you get any developer console output that might help? If you could provide a link where I could see it as well it would help in debugging :). Try my edited version - if that works, there is some error in the contents of the definition.

Comment: I tried your second way and it still did not work. Instead it brought up the default CKEditor, this is really beginning to get on my nerves. I can't see where the problem is. But no I don't get any output. Besides error messages which I fix before running anyway. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Hello. My senior developer came over and gave me a hand. It's not your fault, I had a pair of extra brackets at the bottom which was stopping my javascript from running. I wasn't looking that far down. Well, at least I learned something. Javascript doesn't run if there is a single error! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[`CKEDITOR.replace()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-replace) accepts the ID of the element to replace with the editor and the config. However, you do not need to write:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'txtBodyText', 
    config.toolbar=...
```

it's enough to just use `toolbar`, without the preceding `config`. And also, as pointed above, your JavaScript code is incorrect (notice your `=` instead of `:`):

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'txtBodyText',  {
    toolbar: ...
} );
```

See how it is done in the samples from the CKEditor SDK, e.g. the [Custom Toolbar sample](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/toolbar.html). Scroll down to get the complete source code of the sample.

Don't forget to clear your browser cache after any editor configuration change!

Comment: Your 2nd example is not a valid JS object. This method works fine too, but change it to `CKEDITOR.replace('id', { key: value });` notation :).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Whenever I try to use : instead of =. It expects a ) on the end.

Comment: Hello. My senior developer came over and gave me a hand. It's not your fault, I had a pair of extra brackets at the bottom which was stopping my javascript from running. I wasn't looking that far down. Well, at least I learned something. Javascript doesn't run if there is a single error! Thank you for your help.

Comment: Corrected the code above, sorry about that. I was too hasty copying and deleting redundant code :)